# How to convert DB table with parent son relation to multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, recursion, multidimensional-array

How can I convert a database table like that:

[image]

into a multi-dimensional array like that ?

[image]

I tried a recursive loop like below but can't get it to display properly.

```
function cost_centres_format($items)
{
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        echo $item->name.' - '.$item->parent_id;
        echo '<br/>';
        $sons = $this->purchase_order_model->get_cost_centre_sons($item->internal_purchase_order_cost_centre_id);
        if(count($sons)>0){
            $this->cost_centres_format($sons);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for it:

```
function cost_centres_format($items,$parent_id,$array=array()) {
    foreach($items as $item) {
        if($item->parent_id == $parent_id) {
            $array[] = $item;
            if($item->internal_purchase_order_cost_centre_id>0) {
                $array = cost_centres_format($items,$item->internal_purchase_order_cost_centre_id,$array);
            }
        }
    }
    return $array;
}
$array = cost_centres_format($items,0);
```

Diesel (id:5) will be below Vehicle Maintenance (id:4) because of its original order. You can do an additional sort by name but in your example Capital (id:3) was below Overheads (id:2).

Answer (score 0):

The above code doesn't produce multidimensional array but instead one dimensional array like so :

```
Array
(
 [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [internal_purchase_order_cost_centre_id] => 1
        [name] => Direct Expenses                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
        [parent_id] => 0
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [internal_purchase_order_cost_centre_id] => 4
        [name] => Vehicle Maintenance                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
        [parent_id] => 1
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [internal_purchase_order_cost_centre_id] => 9
        [name] => CN09 AKO                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        [parent_id] => 4
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [internal_purchase_order_cost_centre_id] => 10
        [name] => DY52 BYO                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        [parent_id] => 4
    )

[4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [internal_purchase_order_cost_centre_id] => 14
        [name] => MX08 MVJ                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        [parent_id] => 4
    )

[5] => stdClass Object
    (
        [internal_purchase_order_cost_centre_id] => 15
        [name] => YJ55 TXA                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        [parent_id] => 4
    )

[6] => stdClass Object
    (
        [internal_purchase_order_cost_centre_id] => 5
        [name] => Diesel                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        [parent_id] => 1
    )

[7] => stdClass Object
    (
        [internal_purchase_order_cost_centre_id] => 6
        [name] => Vehicle Rent                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        [parent_id] => 1
    )

[8] => stdClass Object
    (
        [internal_purchase_order_cost_centre_id] => 11
        [name] => Vehicle Repair                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        [parent_id] => 1
    )

[9] => stdClass Object
    (
        [internal_purchase_order_cost_centre_id] => 16
        [name] => CN09 AKO                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        [parent_id] => 11
    )

[10] => stdClass Object
    (
        [internal_purchase_order_cost_centre_id] => 17
        [name] => DY52 BYO                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        [parent_id] => 11
    )

[11] => stdClass Object
    (
        [internal_purchase_order_cost_centre_id] => 18
        [name] => MX08 MVJ                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        [parent_id] => 11
    )

[12] => stdClass Object
    (
        [internal_purchase_order_cost_centre_id] => 19
        [name] => YJ55 TXA                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        [parent_id] => 11
    )

[13] => stdClass Object
    (
        [internal_purchase_order_cost_centre_id] => 2
        [name] => Overheads                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        [parent_id] => 0
    )

[14] => stdClass Object
    (
        [internal_purchase_order_cost_centre_id] => 12
        [name] => Internet Service                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        [parent_id] => 2
    )

[15] => stdClass Object
    (
        [internal_purchase_order_cost_centre_id] => 13
        [name] => Warehouse Rent                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        [parent_id] => 2
    )

[16] => stdClass Object
    (
        [internal_purchase_order_cost_centre_id] => 3
        [name] => Capital                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        [parent_id] => 0
    )

[17] => stdClass Object
    (
        [internal_purchase_order_cost_centre_id] => 7
        [name] => New Stock                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        [parent_id] => 3
    )

[18] => stdClass Object
    (
        [internal_purchase_order_cost_centre_id] => 8
        [name] => New Vehicle                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        [parent_id] => 3
    )
```

)

Comment: Joseph Assem Sobhy: this is not an answer. And nobody will receive a notification when you do this. Add a comment to the corresponding answer instead. And you should add an example how you want your array (instead of an excel screenshot).