# Convert MySQL table with relation to multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a menu table:

`id, slug, label, parent`

Parent has a relation to `id` so if you had:

`1, 'foo-bar', 'Foo Bar', NULL`

This would be a root item whereas:

`2, 'foo', 'Foo ', 1`

Would belong to 'foo-bar'. Then you could have items belonging to `foo` and so on.

How can I turn this into a multi-dimensional menu array in PHP? So I can do things like:

```
<?= $menu['foo-bar']['foo'] // echos 'Foo' ?>
```

My requirements are very similar to [How to convert DB table with parent son relation to multi-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32077219/how-to-convert-db-table-with-parent-son-relation-to-multi-dimensional-array) but the answer there doesn't work; it isn't recursive.

Answer (score 1):

Here is example of `foreach` (non-tested) that can do something that you want.

```
<?php
// $results is your data from database
$menu = array();

foreach($results as $k => $result) {
  $key = $result['id'];  
  $parent = $result['parent'];
  if(!empty($parent)){
   array_push($menu[$parent]['parents'], $result);
  } else {
    unset($results[$k]['parent'];
    $menu[$key] = $result;
  }
}

var_dump($menu);
```