# How to looping hierarcial data with parent id in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to create multilevel foreach and showing hierarcialy,
I have a table like this

```
+----+------------------+-----------+
| id | name             | parent_id |
+----+------------------+-----------+
| 1  | parent1          | 0         |
+----+------------------+-----------+
| 2  | child1           | 1         |
+----+------------------+-----------+
| 3  | parent2          | 0         |
+----+------------------+-----------+
| 4  | child2           | 3         |
+----+------------------+-----------+
| 5  | grandchild1      | 4         |
+----+------------------+-----------+
| 6  | greatgrandchild1 | 5         |
+----+------------------+-----------+
```

and then I want to showing data like this

```
<ul>
 <li> parent1
  <ul>
   <li> child1 </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
<ul>
 <li> parent2 
  <ul>
   <li> child2 
    <ul>
     <li> grandschild1 
      <ul>
        <li> greatgrandchild1
      <ul>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

and then i create the view

```
<?php
$data = $this->db->where('parent_id', '0')->get('mytbl')->result();
echo '<ul>'
foreach ($data as $item)
{
 echo '<li>'.$item->name.'</li>';

   echo '<ul>';

   $data2 = $this->db->where('parent_id',$item_id)->get('mytbl')->result();

   foreach ($data2 as $item2) {

   echo '<li>'.$item2->name.'</li>';

    echo '<ul>';

   $data3 = $this->db->where('parent_id',$item_id)->get('mytbl')->result();

   foreach ($data3 as $item3) {

   echo '<li>'.$item3->name.'</li>';

   // etc ....

  }

  echo '</ul>';

  }

  echo '</ul>';


}
echo '<ul>';
?>
```

and then I think this is not efficient, too many foreach and I just put it into view, Is it possible to create looping like this? without write many of foreach and then how to create this in controller then passing into view,

Anyone know? please help me! Sorry my english is bad.

Comment: how do we know that grandchild1 belongs to parent2 and not to parent1?

Comment: Check this [library](https://github.com/edomaru/codeigniter_multilevel_menu) and this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gBliuKI1Kj4).

Comment: @Vickel, follow recursive relation into the table (parent IDs).

Comment: @Vickel because grandchlid parent_id is 4, id 4 is child2's id which have parent_id 3, id 3 is parent2's id. I guess that makes sense, right?

Comment: checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36200164/convert-mysql-table-with-relation-to-multi-dimensional-array/36200475#36200475

Comment: Is it possible to add a 4th column there? Adding another column for level will make your life easier. eg: add another column `level` parent = 1, child = 2, grandchild = 3. Now on your query, fetch everything, from there work on the data you have and sort them according to level rather than having queries within a loop and another query within that loop which is totally bad programming.

Comment: look @my example you just need 1 db query - there is no need for a level based db concept or anything like that....

Answer (score 1):

i try to give you some idea here

create a Model Category_Model (or something like that)

```
class Category_Model extends CI_Model
{
    public function getCategoryTreeData()
    {
        $query = $this->db
            ->select("*")
            ->from("mytbl")
            ->get();


        $arrTreeById = array();
        $arrTree = $query->result();


        $objTreeWrapper = new stdClass();
        $objTreeWrapper->arrChilds = array();

        foreach($arrTree AS $row)
        {
            $arrTreeById[$row->id] = $row;
            $row->arrChilds = array();
        }

        foreach($arrTree AS $objItem)
        {
            if (isset($arrTreeById[$objItem->parent_id]))   $arrTreeById[$objItem->parent_id]->arrChilds[] = $objItem;
            elseif ($objItem->parent_id == 0)
            {
                $objTreeWrapper->arrChilds[] = $objItem;
            }
        }

        return $objTreeWrapper;
    }
}
```

then in your controller

```
class Category extends CI_Controller
{
    public function your_function()
    {
        $this->load->model("Category_Model");

        $arrViewData = array(
            "objTree" => $this->Category_Model->getCategoryTreeData()
        );

        $this->load->view("your_view",$arrViewData);
    }
}
```

and finally your view

```
function setCategoryTree($objTree)
{
    if (count($objTree->arrChilds) > 0)
    {
        echo "<ul>";
        foreach($objTree->arrChilds AS $objItem)
        {
            echo "<li>".$objItem->name;

            setCategoryTree($objItem);
            echo "</li>";

        }
        echo "</ul>";

    }
}

setCategoryTree($objTree);
```

Comment: OMG It's so difficult to understand I thought that gonna be easy, I think I should to learn more, hahaha anyway thanks for your answer, but I really don't understand, LOL

Comment: haha and i thought its quite simple ;)
if you use Codeigniter you should be familiar with the mvc paradigm and after that i don't think the code is that difficult to understand :D

Answer (score 0):

Simple recursive function can do that (which can be easily modified for Codeigniter if needed):

```
<body>      
    <?php
        function getFamily($parentID){
            global $link;
            $query = "SELECT * FROM family WHERE parent_id = ".$parentID;
            $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                    echo '<ul>
                        <li>'.$row['name'].'</li>';
                        //recursive call
                        getFamily($row['id']);
                    echo '</ul>';
                }
            }
        }

        $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'database');
        getFamily(0);
     ?>       
</body>
```

Output:

```
parent1
    child1

parent2
    child2
        grandchild1
            greatgrandchild1
```